# How can i test 20000 users with live stream?

Tags: automation, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to test 20000 users watch live stream and need to capture screen after every 2 minutes. is phantomjs is good?
Please suggest a good way.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following combination:

1. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) - to simulate 19999 users consuming the stream. Check out [How to Load Test HTTP Live Media Streaming (HLS) with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-http-live-media-streaming-hls-jmeter) guide for details.
2. PhantomJS is quite good for simulating a single user so you can launch in in a separate thread to mimic remaining user and take screenshots, however most likely you won't be able to capture streaming content.

By the way, you can even integrate PhantomJS with JMeter, see [Web Driver Tutorial](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) and [PhantonJS Driver Config](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PhantomJSDriverConfig/)